# AirPlay icon is disappearing on when user disconnect the external playback

Tags: airplay, mpvolumeview

I am using airplay icon and volume slider in app. Once user connect the airplay video is casting to the appleTV and volume slider is getting hide(as expected).Now navigate back to previous page and again come to player page to play video when airplay is connected then casting is fine in case too.but when user disconnect the airplay then volumeSlider is now showing but airplay icon is getting disappear.

Please suggest any solution to show the airplay icon always.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behaviour. As detailed in the iOS [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpvolumeview) about `MPVolumeView`, the Airplay button is supposed to only appear when one or more external accessories are available for playback.

To bypass this, I'd suggest implementing your own airplay button as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879210/ios-how-can-i-display-an-airplay-popup-menu-in-swift/45007382#45007382)