# iOS - How can I display an 'AirPlay' popup menu in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, airplay

How can I display an AirPlay popup menu in my Swift project? (Many applications like Spotify can display one like below):

[image]

Comment: Look at adding a 'MPVolumeView' to your app. You don't actually create the menu but by having that control it will allow the user to see that menu when they click on it.

Answer (score 10):

After all it seems there is no easy and straightforward way to make a custom button display the system's Airplay menu.

However, @totiG pointer me to an interesting resource and I created a script that creates the standard Volume Control outside of the visible area of the screen a simulates a click on the Airplay button:

```
func showAirplay() {
    let rect = CGRect(x: -100, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    let airplayVolume = MPVolumeView(frame: rect)
    airplayVolume.showsVolumeSlider = false
    self.view.addSubview(airplayVolume)
    for view: UIView in airplayVolume.subviews {
        if let button = view as? UIButton {
            button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
            break
        }
    }
    airplayVolume.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

After running this code the following popup menu appears:

[image]

Comment: Using this code I got only transparent rect without any slider or button.

Comment: @SergeyDi: I have added a screenshot above to show what this code does in my environment. Doesn't it work the same way for you? What iOS version are you running?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a sweet little workaround to having to use the MPVolumeView's button.

1. Create a MPVolumeView, and hide it somewhere in the view hierarchy.
2. Whenever you want to display the picker:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:NSSelectorFromString(@"_displayAudioRoutePicker") to:myVolumeView from:myView forEvent:nil];`

**Optional 3:** On iPad you'll need to pass a UIEvent otherwise the popover will just be entered at the top of the screen and it'll look wonky. Capture the event from `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;` and pass it into our call.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but is this a private API? (Will my app be accepted to the app store if I use this?)