# How to display the AirPlay Menu SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13, airplay

Thanks to the airplay audio systemName emoji I made a nice icon

```
Button(action: {
        showAirplay()
}, label: {
    Image(systemName: "airplayaudio")
        .imageScale(.large)
})

func showAirplay() {
       ???
}
```

But I have no idea how to display the famous menu :

[image]

Comment: tried to make a UIViewControllerRepresentable with that embed in :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879210/ios-how-can-i-display-an-airplay-popup-menu-in-swift but does **not** seem to work on my side...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it myself :D
Like said in the comment I have to "embed it inside" UIKit and use it in SwiftUI

Firstly :

```
struct AirPlayButton: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AirPlayButton>) -> UIViewController {
        return AirPLayViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<AirPlayButton>) {

    }
}
```

Then classic ViewController where we know from ages **how** to show this famous AirPlay menu popup :

```
class AirPLayViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let isDarkMode = self.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark

        let button = UIButton()
        let boldConfig = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
        let boldSearch = UIImage(systemName: "airplayaudio", withConfiguration: boldConfig)

        button.setImage(boldSearch, for: .normal)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.tintColor = isDarkMode ? .white : .black

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.showAirPlayMenu(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button)
    }

    @objc func showAirPlayMenu(_ sender: UIButton){ // copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/44909445/7974174
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        let airplayVolume = MPVolumeView(frame: rect)
        airplayVolume.showsVolumeSlider = false
        self.view.addSubview(airplayVolume)
        for view: UIView in airplayVolume.subviews {
            if let button = view as? UIButton {
                button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
                break
            }
        }
        airplayVolume.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Finally in SwiftUI simply call :

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            AirPlayButton().frame(width: 40, height: 40) // (important to be consistent with this frame, like that it is nicely centered... see button.frame in AirPlayViewController)

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Wrapping the AirPlay UIView for SwiftUI seems to be the best and simplest solution.

```
struct AirPlayView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {

        let routePickerView = AVRoutePickerView()
        routePickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        routePickerView.activeTintColor = UIColor.red
        routePickerView.tintColor = UIColor.white

        return routePickerView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
VStack {
  AirPlayView()
}
```

Comment: Apple details a slightly different view in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avroutepickerview).

Answer (score 1):

I have modified [Max's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62138637/2227743) to my needs and thought it could be useful to share. It adapts to the superview with autolayout and has a method to call its action.

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct AirPlayView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    private let routePickerView = AVRoutePickerView()

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AirPlayView>) -> UIView {
        UIView()
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AirPlayView>) {
        routePickerView.tintColor = .white
        routePickerView.activeTintColor = .systemPink
        routePickerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        routePickerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        uiView.addSubview(routePickerView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            routePickerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.topAnchor),
            routePickerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.leadingAnchor),
            routePickerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.bottomAnchor),
            routePickerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    func showAirPlayMenu() {
        for view: UIView in routePickerView.subviews {
            if let button = view as? UIButton {
                button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can still use it directly as a view, as in Max's answer, but also you can embed it in another view like a button and trigger the menu by hand, like I needed to:

```
@State private var airPlayView = AirPlayView()

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        // other views

        Button(action: {
            // other actions
            airPlayView.showAirPlayMenu()
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text("Show AirPlay menu")
                
                Spacer()
                
                airPlayView
                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
            }
        }
        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func showAirplay() {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    let airplayVolume = MPVolumeView(frame: rect)
    airplayVolume.showsVolumeSlider = false
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.addSubview(airplayVolume)
    for view: UIView in airplayVolume.subviews {
      if let button = view as? UIButton {
        button.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
        break
      }
    }
    airplayVolume.removeFromSuperview()
  }
```